# How to create a simple key-value store in nodejs as a CLI, without use of any 3rd party libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

Create a simple key-value store in nodejs as a CLI without using any 3rd party libraries.
It should have the following commands:
1. kvs add {KEY} {VALUE}
2. kvs remove {KEY}
3. kvs get {KEY}

Comment: Your question is far too broad and is in danger of being closed. Please edit your post and refine your question down to a specific issue. Review this [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article for tips on how to ask constructive questions and get constructive answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is far too broad a question. It's more like 10 different google searches. Here are results from a few:

Read key and value arguments passed

[Process command line args with Node](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/)

Storage method, assuming you're fine with text file storage, as you did say it's a simple app:

[Reading and writing files with Node](https://tutorialedge.net/nodejs/reading-writing-files-with-nodejs/)

To turn your app into a command line command (also includes some styling guides):

[Creating a command line application with Node](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/18/command-line-app-with-nodejs)

The text for each link is exactly what I googled for each result. I recommend doing a little more research before asking the community to essentially write your app for you. Google answers for specific problems you face during development. Get to a point where you get stuck and do not understand why, and submit a question with specific details as to what your goal is, what errors you're getting, and what you've tried already. Good luck